# SQL Server : Unable to update table with less data length of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi I have `TableA` and `TableB` which have `NOTES` column common with data type `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. I am trying to update `NOTES` column in `TableA` with data in `TableB`
The Maximum `DATALENGTH` of NOTES column in `TableB` is 7200. When I ran query, I am getting

> "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated."

I found the record with `DATALENGTH 720`0, and I tried to update the value with 'ABC' like below

```
UPDATE TableA
SET Notes= 'ABC' 
WHERE ID= 111287
```

Still I am getting the data truncated error. Please help

Comment: Have you ran `LEN()` on that column to make sure you found all instances where it was > 7200?

Comment: What is the data type of the NOTES column in TableB?

Comment: Hi data type of NOTES in both tables is NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Both columns in TableA and TableB are `NVARCHAR(MAX)` ? Then what 7200 limit is about?

Comment: Check DDL of each table. I guess one of them is not `(max)` actually.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?

Comment: Try deleting the record and insert a new one with corrected values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your question or comments regarding a "limit". The DATALENGTH() function simply returns the number of actual bytes stored in the column for the actual record. I would suggest you script out both tables and post them, or check [sys].[columns] for the actual data types.